# Uso del console.log en los diferentes navegadores

Tags: consola, firefox, chrome, safari

Tengo un problemilla con el codigo que pondre a continuacion:

```
var x;
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    console.log(i);
    x = prompt("numero?");
    if(i == x){
        console.log("Correcto!")
    }else{
        console.log("Incorrecto")
    }
}
```

Resulta que cuando lo ejecuto no me sale nada tanto en la consola de chrome como en la de safari pero si llego hasta el final del programa y lo vuelvo a ejecutar entonces si me sale todo correcto por consola(en firefox no me pasa eso y me sale directamente desde la primera vez),a que puede ser debido porque ya no se que mas hacer y seguro que es una tonteria

Comment: Quizás esto te ayude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015540/console-log-doesnt-work-in-safari-6-0-web-inspector

Comment: *****Edito : Mi problema es que la primera vez que ejecuto no me sale absolutamente nada en la consola hasta que acaba elprograma y me salen todos los console.log de golpe, luego actualizo la pagina para volver a cargar el programa y si me salen todos los console.log perfectamente en tiempo de ejecucion, no es que este desactivado nada de la consolacomo pone en algun comentario del enlace que me has pasado y me pasa tanto en chrome como en safari, y no asi en firefox, muchas gracias :)


pd: me interesa sobretodo en chrome que es el navegador que uso